# How to configuring Mailgun for NextAuth

Tags: mailgun, next-auth

I am trying to use Mailgin as Email provider uses email to send "magic links" that can be used to sign in.

```
import clientPromise from "@/app/lib/connectDb";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";

import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";

const handler = NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
        EmailProvider({
            server: {
                host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
                port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                    pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
                },
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
            maxAge: 10 * 60, // Magic links are valid for 10 min only
        }),
    ],

     
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

env variables are:

```
MAIL_SERVER_HOST="smtp.mailgun.org"
EMAIL_SERVER_PORT="587"
EMAIL_SERVER_USER="postmaster@mydomain"
EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD="key-**********"
```

I get an error
`message: 'Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Setting up NextAuth's EmailProvider with Mailgun (via SMTP)

Given you likely won't reuse all 4 SMTP environment variables outside of this one file (or import them in isolation throughout your app), you can simplify the `EmailProvider`'s server configuration as follows:

```js
EmailProvider({
  from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
  server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER, 
  maxAge: 10 * 60, // Magic links are valid for 10 min only
}),
```

Then consolidate the environment variables:

```
# Email Sender Info
EMAIL_FROM=My App <name@mydomain.com>

# Magic Link Email Server
EMAIL_SERVER=smtp://postmaster@mydomain.com:smtp_password@smtp.mailgun.org:587
```

**Good to know:** If your Mailgun account is hosted in Europe, the host becomes: `smtp.eu.mailgun.org`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I did some mistakes. I used the wrong SMTP credentials. From the Mailgun dashboard, I created the new SMTP user and then used the user name and the newly generated password

```
MAIL_SERVER_HOST="smtp.mailgun.org"
EMAIL_SERVER_PORT=587 
EMAIL_SERVER_USER="postmaster@mydomain" // ex. me@mg.mydomain.com - my domain was setup as mg.mydomain.com 
EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD=****** // SMTP user password not api key that I have used earlier "key-**********" ( wrong)
```